# how to get the sql output as below,

Tags: sql, count, pivot

```
Name.    Gender
a          F
b          M
c.         M
d          F
e          F
```

How to get output as below

```
Male      Female
2           3
```

Need some sql suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation. In standard SQL:

```
select 
    sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) male,
    sum(case when gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) female
from mytable
```